# Sending data using zmq from python to Unity3d (C#) using PUB-SUB

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, zeromq

I have a python program communicating with a C# program connected to a Unity3D environment. The part where the python program subscribes to the C# program is working. However, the Unity3D environment is not subscribing to the data that the python code is publishing to the defined zmq socket. I tried sending all kinds of data and also try to check what is coming in by printing it on the debug window. But C# is not being able to subscribe to it in any way.
The C# code could subscribe to data published by a C++ code. Is it not possible to publish data from python to C#? Or is there a different technique to achieve the python to C# zmq communication?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). This post could benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution on Stack Overflow itself. I will also read up about how to ask good questions. Thanks for the feedback.